# Remove border in focus - mat-list

Tags: css, angular, mat-list

I'm having a problem with a border in the mat-list-item that I can't solve, I did look for a solution in the the material's website, but don't find it.

When I click on icon this blue border appears, I didn't find the css class that makes this happen, has anyone been through something similar?

[image]

My code:

```
 <mat-list>
     <mat-list-item class="item-list" routerLink="/panel/home" [routerLinkActive]="['active-item']">
        <mat-icon matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
     </mat-list-item>
     <mat-list-item class="item-list" routerLink="/profile" [routerLinkActive]="['active-item']">
        <mat-icon matListIcon>class</mat-icon>
     </mat-list-item>
     <mat-list-item class="item-list" routerLink="/student" [routerLinkActive]="['active-item']">
        <mat-icon matListIcon>assignment</mat-icon>
     </mat-list-item>
     <mat-list-item class="item-list">
        <mat-icon matListIcon>directions_run</mat-icon>
     </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
```

The 'active-item' class, make a that purple border-right, but not the blue border.

```
.active-item{
  border-right: 2px solid $primary-color;
  mat-icon {
    color: $primary-color 
  }
}
```

I use Angular with Material UI.

Comment: try to add this css: `button:focus{ outline: none }`

Comment: the property works on mat-list-item class: mat-list-item{ outline: none }. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

In case of Buttons insert this to **styles.css** :

```
button:focus, 
button:active:focus, 
button.active:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    outline-style: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Is outline-style: none !important really necessary? My IntelliJ highlights it and says "Property outline-style duplicates property outline".

Answer (score 3):

try :

```
mat-icon,mat-icon.matListIcon{
    outline:none !important;

}
```

Comment: the property works on mat-list-item class: mat-list-item{ outline: none }. Thanks!!